# Opening a .jpg image in Camera Raw

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can one open a `.jpg` image in Adobe Photoshop's Camera Raw directly from Windows Explorer in Windows 7?

I know how to open it via Bridge and from inside Photoshop, I'd just like to know whether I can open some `.jpg`s from Windows Explorer by right-clicking and choosing Camera Raw...

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop CS5 - Edit - Preferences - File Handling:

Camera Raw Preferences - JPEG and TIFF Handling

Select "automatically open all supported JPEGs"

Now when you right click a JPEG and select open in CS5 it will open in Camera RAW. I don't normally have CS5 configured like this but seems to work ok.

Comment: Know that one but thanks anyway. I was interested in something more along the lines of opening only some `.jpeg`s in Camera Raw and some directly in Photoshop by using it something like `Open with...` and then have the option of choosing either Photoshop or Camera Raw plugin. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Sorry, can't see a way to get Camera RAW on the right click menu. I have Bridge as an "Open With" choice - so if I want to edit in Camera RAW I right click and open in Bridge (thumbnail view) and then select open in Camera RAW. Any JPEG I want straight into CS5 I right click and open with CS5.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... Hope someone else has any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I tried it and it opened...

Open your cs5 page go to `File` and click `Open as`. Select the image with the corresponding file name. Click `Open as`.  Select `Photoshop Raw`. Click `Image Sequence` and click `Open`. It will show a box (frame rate 30) click `OK`. It will show another box. Click on `Continue` and it will display your image on your working page.